# Problem with java.util.Scanner & strings

Tags: java, terminal, java.util.scanner

I tried to implement a simple yes/no input with java.util.Scanner. My code looks like this:

```
public boolean ask(String quest){
  String answ = scann(quest + " (y/n)");
  answ = answ.split("")[1].toLowerCase();
  if(answ == "y") { return true; }
  if(answ == "n") { return false;}

  //if answer isnt understood
  printOut("Please enter 'y' or 'n'! Answered: " + answ +"!");
  return ask(quest);
}
```

To make it short: It ends up with an infinite request for the answer. The answer is never understood, I got no clue what I did wrong.

Comment: maybe it should be `answ = answ.split("")[0].toLowerCase();`??

Comment: Nope, the first split is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `==` to compare strings in Java (well, you can, but it's not the right way to compare their literal values). You need to use `equals()`:

```
  if ("y".equals(answ)) { return true; }
  if ("n".equals(answ)) { return false; }
```

Comment: Jup. Use "y".equals(answ) if you want to avoid probably possible null pointer exceptions.